# How to calculate the "Nearest Neighbour" for multiple sources in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, nearest-neighbor

The "Nearest Neighbour" problem is very common when working with spatial data.

There's even some [nice, simple documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor) about how to do it with MS Sql Server in their docs!

I'm usually seeing examples where it's using 1x source Lat/Long and it returns the 'x' number of nearest neighbour Lat/Longs. Fine...

e.g.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012  
GO  
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(-121.626 47.8315)';  
SELECT TOP(7) SpatialLocation.ToString(), City FROM Person.Address  
WHERE SpatialLocation.STDistance(@g) IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY SpatialLocation.STDistance(@g);
```

In my case, I have *multiple* Lat/Long sources ... and for each source, need to return the 'x' number of nearest neighbours.

Here's my schema

```
Table: SomeGeogBoundaries
LocationId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (it's not an identity, but a PK & FK)
CentrePoint GEOGRAPHY

Index:
Spatial Index on CentrePoint column. [Geography || MEDIUM, MEDIUM, HIGH, HIGH]
```

Sample data:

```
LocationId | CP Lat/Long
1          | 10,10
2          | 11,11
3          | 20,20

..
```

So for each location in this table, I need to find the closest.. say 5 other locations.

### Update

So far, it looks like using a `CURSOR` is the only way .. but I'm open to more *set* based solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the nearest neighbors within the same set?

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeGeogBoundaries as b
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(5) CentrePoint
   FROM SomeGeogBoundaries as t
   WHERE t.CentrePoint.STInsersects(b.CentrePoint.STBuffer(100))
   ORDER by b.CentrePoint.STDistance(t.CentrePoint)
) AS nn
```

Two notes.

1. The `where` clause in the `outer apply` is to limit the search to (in this case) points that are within 100 meters of eachother (assuming that you're using an SRID whose native unit of measure is meters). That may or may not be appropriate for you. If not, just omit the `where` clause.
2. I think this is *still* a cursor. Don't fool yourself into thinking that just because there is nary a `declare cursor` statement to be seen that the db engine has much of a choice but to iterate through your table and evaluate the `apply` for each row.

Comment: Sweet! I first did a cursor - took 1h 2 min. Then replaced the cursor with your code, took 58 mins. So basically the same. As u suggested, it's probably because it was a cursor internally. Also, I'm assuming (again) that I was using the spatial index because I replaced your where clause with `t.CP.STDistance(b.CP) IS NOT NULL` to make sure it's using the spatial index.